# ThreadAbortException When Editing in 9.2

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Getting the following error when trying to edit in 9.2. When I click on the pencil icon it simply refreshes the pages and does not go into edit mode. This site has just been deployed to a staging server and is working fine on my local VM. It is not due to third party module because it is affecting more than one page.

Edit mode works when page accessed from browser on the staging server. When accessing the staging link remotely, the same error occurs. Looks like a 302 to the page is happening when accessing it remotely.

Other users reporting similar problem:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/539819/scope/posts/cannot-edit-any-pages

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/unable-to-edit-a-page-via-the-pencil-icon-on-the-page

2018-09-18 12:16:26,639 [ServerName][Thread:14][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
at System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread()
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
at Evoq.Content.Library.ContentEditor.ContentEditorManager.AutoSetUserMode()
at Evoq.Content.Library.ContentEditor.ContentEditorManager.OnInit(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
at Evoq.Content.Library.UI.Skins.EventListeners.EvoqContentSkinEventListener.OnSkinInit(Object sender, SkinEventArgs e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message that was generated was totally misleading, as suspected.

We recently had our entire site re-branded and this included new fonts. One of these fonts was “.woff2”. I neglected to add a mime type for this font in IIS on our staging server. When we added the mime type to IIS for this font, the edit issue resolved itself!

Answer (score 0):

That is likely normal behavior of `Response.Recirect()` that you must be calling. It will always abort current thread and throw an `ThreadAbortException`
To fix this just pass`endResponde` value set to `false`

Comment: This is happening on every page of the site so it's not module-specific. It only happens on our staging server and not on my local dev machine. If this was down to code we wrote ourselves then I get what you're saying...